# GeoWebCache OpenLayers WMS request structure

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, geocaching

I'm developing a GIS app that makes use of GeoServer and GeoWebCache for serving requests, and OpenLayers for frontend. WMS requests to the GeoServer are served with no issues. But when I make a request through GeoWebCache, nothing is returned to the client. I've enabled Direct WMS Integration in GeoWebCache configuration. I'm using GeoWebCache integrated in GeoServer. My request is as shown below:

```
var wmslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
   "Kenya Administrative Boundaries",
   "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?", 
   {layers: 'kenya_admin', format:'image/png', transparent: true},
   {opacity: 1.0, isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
);
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

But the layer is not loaded. Any advice on what I may be doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of Geoserver's [Geowebcache documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html) is that if you enable Direct WMS Integration, you can simply point your request to the regular wms service, include "TILED=true" and Geoserver handles the rest. I.e, all you have to do is change your request to:

```
var wmslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
   "Kenya Administrative Boundaries",
   "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms?", 
   {layers: 'kenya_admin', format:'image/png', transparent: true, TILED: 'true'},
   {opacity: 1.0, isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
);
```

I've done that with my OpenLayers site and it works...
Cheers
M

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aragon. I'll try it out right away, and let you know my findings.

Comment: Aragon, it doesn't work for me. May be its a projection issue. But I'll test again later.